# Delzant polytopes and combinatorial types

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, convex-polytopes

At first, let us see the following matheoverflow question,

[About a Delzant polytope. (In particular dodecahedron)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58573/about-a-delzant-polytope-in-particular-dodecahedron/)

The question is whether (combinatorial) regular dodecahedron can be realized as a Delzant polytope or not.

A combinatorial type of a polytope means a face-lattice structure.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice

When I  learned Delzant polytopes, in fact, my first question was that what kind of combinatorial type allow Delzant realization.

Obviously the first requirement is  that it should be a rational polytope.
Fortunately,  all 3-dimensional (combinatorial) polytopes always rational realization. 
Moreover, 3-dimensional polytopes are identified with 3-vertex connected planar graph by Steiniz theorem,
So let me restrict the question to only 3-dimensional cases only.

On superficial consideration, 
it seems quite doable to try check that a 3-dimensional polyhedron allow Delzant realization or not.

I think it is very natural question, but I couldn't find any literature.
Is there any study concering combinatorial type  of polytopes and Delzant condition? Is it trivially true? or is it meaningless question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only theorem i know.

[**Theorem**] Let P be a 3-dimensional Delzant polytope. Then P has at least one triangular or quadrangular face.

see [**C. Delaunay**], *On Hyperbolicity of Toric Real Threefolds*, IMRN International Mathematics Research Notices 2005, No. 51.